# JS Turn list text color with button click all one color

Tags: javascript, list, text, colors

I am a beginner and I just do not know what to do. I tried various things like function click, getElement and onclick etc. but I just don't know why it's not working and what I should do in the first place. All I ever find is the button color and background color but nothing on text color and list. I just couldn't find a proper solution anywhere :/

I have a list (it's two seperate ones because of how I wrote the CSS lol)  of rainbow colors written out and their respective colors (there are more but I didn't want the post to be too long because of all the colors). I wanted all of them to turn black at once when you click on a button.
The files are all seperate.

it looks somewhat like this:

```css
.list {
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
}
#red {
    list-style-type: circle;
    color: red;

}
#orange {
    list-style-type: circle;
    color: orange;
}

#yellow {
    list-style-type: circle;
    color:yellow;
}

#brown {
    color: brown;
}

#grey {
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <ul>
    <li id="red"> red </li>
    <li id="orange"> orange </li>
    <li id="yellow"> yellow </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class=list2>
    <ol start=3>
    <li id="brown"> brown </li>
    <li id="grey"> grey</li>
    </ol>
    </div>
   
    <button id="black">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Looks like you've only included your html (and maybe even some of that is missing since you mention a button but the markup doesn't include any). Please ensure all the relevant information for the question is included and formatted correctly (your HTML has a lot of extra '\'s for some reason).

Comment: @DanielBlack I fixed it! I didn't realize posting it added those lol Is that better for understanding my problem?

Comment: Look up how to addEventListener to an element (in this case, the button) and put your Javascript into your snippet if you are still stuck.

Comment: @nonamex I've added an answer now, let me know if there is anything in the answer which can be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an event listener to the button will allow you to fire a method whenever it is clicked. Once you have a method firing on click, you can set up a method to pull all the list elements to updated, loop through and add a class to set the color to black.

I've made the changes for you below. Note that I've updated your ids to classes, as it is typically best to control styles by class rather than id, as classes can be reused, while ids should only be assigned to a single element. I also added a new `black` class which set the color to black. Finally I added a common class to all list elements to allow pulling them specifically.

```js
//grab the button element
var button = document.querySelector("#black");

//attach event listener, will fire the changeColorToBlack method whenever the button is clicked
button.addEventListener("click",changeColorToBlack)

function changeColorToBlack(){
  //grab the list elements to change color
  var listElements = document.querySelectorAll(".list-el")  
  for(var el of listElements){  
    //add the 'black' class to all the list elements
    el.classList.add("black")
  }
}
```

```css
.list {
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

.list2 {
    margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
}
.red {
    list-style-type: circle;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;

}
.orange {
    list-style-type: circle;
    font-style: italic;
    color: orange;
}

.yellow {
    list-style-type: circle;
    font-style: italic;
    color:yellow;
}

.brown {
    font-style: italic;
    color: brown;
}

.black{
  color: black !important; /*Set to important to override other colors*/
}

.grey {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <ul>
    <li class="red list-el"> red </li>
    <li class="orange list-el"> orange </li>
    <li class="yellow list-el"> yellow </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class=list2>
    <ol start=3>
    <li class="brown list-el"> brown </li>
    <li class="grey list-el"> grey</li>
    </ol>
    </div>
   
    <button id="black">Click me</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much! I have been on this for days. I couldn't figure out what went wrong in my studies. You explained it so easily, so that I was able to correct what I learned wrong and even added to it! Thank you so much :) Have a nice day or evening.

Answer (score 0):

Use "document.querySelectorAll();" for list tag and just iterate through it while changing the color